# notifyDataSetChanged didn't work on adapter

Tags: java, android

I have activity and 3 fragments in ViewPage.

In last fragment I have recycleView, if i move to this page i want to refresh recycle view and its work only if I call:

```
 mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(mListener.loadLocationList());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This should work aswell after call notifyDataSetChanged but didn't.
What can we wrong ?

in last fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(mListener.loadLocationList());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

 private class HistoryFragmentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (HISTORY_FRAGMENT_SELECTED.equals(intent.getAction())){
                updateLocationList();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateLocationList() {
         mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(mListener.loadLocationList());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

i wanted `notifydatasetchanged` instead of 2 lines in `updatelocationlist()`

LocationAdapter:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder> {

    private LinkedList<LatLng> mDataset;

    public static class LocationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View mTextView;
        public LocationViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    public LocationAdapter(LinkedList<LatLng> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        LocationViewHolder vh = new LocationViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder locationViewHolder, int position) {
       TextView textView = locationViewHolder.mTextView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
       textView.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position)));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more of your code. For instance, how did you setup your recyclerview?

Comment: added a lot, check now

Comment: How were you doing that notify in your `updateLocationList` method? Have you tried calling `mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but also no refresh

Comment: make your adapter variable  static and then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: How are you managing the list passed to the RecyclerView adapter? You will have to modify the same instance while updating. Make sure you are not creating a new instance.

Comment: "make your adapter variable static and then use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" not smart advise, don't do it

Comment: @purcha why are you thinking that method onReceive() is calling?

Comment: yes, i debugged, onReceive is calling and its work only if i create always new LocationAdapter into onReceive, so it must calling

Comment: Could you add LocationAdapter code here?

Comment: added, must be good imo

Comment: just for sure is onReceive calls in UI thread try this         if (HISTORY_FRAGMENT_SELECTED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateLocationList();
                }
            });
        }

Comment: @purcha It is not advisable to create Adapter multiple times. Your onReceive may get called multiple times and this can lead to multiple objects of adapter to be created. You can have one adapter object and one list object, you can just modify the list or set the new list in the adapter.

Comment: this running in UI thread, checked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set data only in your adapter's constructor.

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged` you can't expect that your adapter will take new data magically. You have to set it by yourself.
My suggestion would be add a setData method in your adapter and call it before `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Something like this in your adapter:

```
public void setData(LinkedList<LatLng> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset
}
```

and in your caller:

```
private void updateLocationList() {
    mAdapter.setData(mListener.loadLocationList());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```